# Which logfile(s) log(s) errors reading a cd?

Tags: log, logging, cd-drive, error-handling

I introduce a CD-RW, maybe blank (I really don't know), and after a little movement inside the reader, the CD is ejected without any message at all. I would like to know what is going on and the reason why it is ejected. How can I know that in Natty. 
The CD reader is working OK because I can read other CD's. It only gave me problems writing from Natty, a few days ago, but with MacOS there was no problem.
Thank you

**Edit:** Maybe there is no error, but then, how can I know what is in the Cd if there is anything?

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal and run:

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

Leave the terminal open and drop the CD in the tray, let it read and eject. You should see the messages and the error(s) in the terminal. Get out of *tail* with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: I saw nothing about the cd at the end of syslog. Anyway, this time I introduced the cd while executing tail -f (why sudo?), as u suggest, and nothing new was logged, but the cd was not ejected, not mounted either, and no message that a blank cd was introduced either.

Comment: I only hear the CD drive start to spin, then the head moving, then only spinning. I can eject without problem with _eject_ command (how else?). (BTW, you get out of _tail_ with Ctrl-C)

Comment: If I try to mount it: `$ sudo mount -t iso9660 -o defaults /dev/sr0 /media/cdrom`, I receive this message:
`mount: block device /dev/sr0 is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sr0,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so`

Comment: Oops, you are quite right; it's Ctrl+c. sudo because syslog used to be not readable by mortal users, only super-users. It has changed and I am old. It is interesting that mount even points you to syslog. I think your message suggests the CD is corrupted, scratched, etc. and not recognizable as a CD at all. I wonder if you can try to reformat it.

Comment: That is what I am thinking because when I try to mount it, in syslog I find:
`Nov 27 .... Sense: Unable to recover table-of-contents
...
end_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 4096
... sr 0:0:0:0: [sr0] Unhandled sense code
...
... sr 0:0:0:0: [sr0]  Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
... sr 0:0:0:0: [sr0]  Add. Sense: Unable to recover table-of-contents
...
... end_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 64
... isofs_fill_super: bread failed, dev=sr0, iso_blknum=16, block=16`

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to erase all, after trying some other thing, like other pc, because I am not sure it doesn't have some music I want there :-(. The thing is I think the user should receive some message.